# Can I directly add variable to xpath value in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

From a table I have founded the rowNumber to use it in xpath(inside tr) expression below, dynamically .
But when I am trying to use just the rowNumber without + operator and double quotes(i.e. tr[rowNumber]), it is showing an error. rowNumber is in int, then why is it necessary to add double quotes and + operator and why cannot we just write the variable name inside tr .

This is the code where error is seen

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='stock']/tbody/tr[rowNumber]/td[1]")).click();
```

This is the correct code

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='stock']/tbody/tr["+rowNumber+"]/td[1]")).click();
```

Comment: I would assume `rowNumber` is an int type ?

Comment: @cruisepandey Yes rowNumber is in int type

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `rowNumber` defined like this:

```
int rowNumber = 10;
```

and if you directly use the rowNumber in the XPath like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='stock']/tbody/tr[rowNumber]/td[1]")).click();
```

the problem with this approach is, your xpath will look for `rowNumber` for tr tag. Just like see the `td[1]`.

and `tr[rowNumber]` is invalid since the basic XPath expression is

```
//tagName[@attributeName='attributeValue']
```

so in order to parse the variable, we have to use `'" +var_name+ "'`

so something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='stock']/tbody/tr[' "+rowNumber+" ']/td[1]")).click();
```

should work